# Windows Azure Drive - Access Denied Exception

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to write a test WCF service which writes image files into Azure Drive storage:

Below is the code I have written:

```
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("DataConnectionString"));
            blobStorage = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            CloudBlobContainer container = blobStorage.GetContainerReference("mydrives");
            container.CreateIfNotExist();

            CloudPageBlob pageBlob = container.GetPageBlobReference("myvhd");
            CloudDrive drive = new CloudDrive(pageBlob.Uri, storageAccount.Credentials);

            try
            {
                drive.Create(100);
                driveLetter = drive.Mount(0, DriveMountOptions.None);
                var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                var fileName = string.Format("{0:10}_{1}{2}", DateTime.Now.Ticks, Guid.NewGuid(), fileExtension);
                File.WriteAllBytes(driveLetter + "\\" + fileName, file.FileStream);
            }
            catch (CloudDriveException e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
```

file.FileStream is the byte array that I am getting from Silverlight client.

This code works perfectly when I run it locally. I could even see the drive blobs and images uploaded using the storage emulator viewer.

But as soon as I publish it to the cloud and run it, I get the following exception:

```
<InnerException i:nil="true"/><Message>Access to the path 'd:\1634586886770888071_aa98357b-888d-4dde-a231-1ca5d5c73b49.jpeg' is denied.</Message><StackTrace>   
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)&#xD;
       at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)&#xD;
       at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)&#xD;
       at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)&#xD;
       at System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(String path, Byte[] bytes)&#xD;
       at ProcessService.FileService.UploadDCMToDrive(FileToTransfer file) in C:\Users\Vinod\Desktop\TestAzure_Vinod\ProcessService\FileService.svc.cs:line 68&#xD;
       at SyncInvokeUploadDCMToDrive(Object , Object[] , Object[] )&#xD;
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)&#xD;
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace><Type>System.UnauthorizedAccessException</Type>
```

I tried starting the application with elevated permissions (as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568380/windows-azure-exception-access-to-the-path-xyz-exe-is-denied)) but I still get the same error. Can anyone shed some light on this please?

**UPDATE**: I created a folder using the below code:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(driveLetter + "\\images");
if (!di.Exists)
  di.Create();
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'd:\images\test.jpeg
```

It's really weird :-(

Comment: Strange. You shouldn't be using the root of drive D: -- that's reserved for Azure's Windows partition.

Comment: Ok, I will create a folder in the root folder using the DirectoryInfo class. Let me see what happens.

Comment: Updated the original post. I am getting a different error after creating a folder under root.

Comment: What's strange is that Azure shouldn't be giving you drive D:.

Comment: Do several instances try to write to the drive at the same time? AFAIK, a drive can only be mounted with write access from only one instance at the same time.

Comment: I think this has something to do with the way you're mounting the drive each time this gets called. When I first tried it, I got `a:`. After running a few times, I'm now on `d:` so I think there is a way to optimize this...